# why an active object can't go through a hole in a passive object?

Tags: objects, physics, faces

I have this scene
[image]

but when I start the motion, the ball still floating in an invisible face of the cylinder
[image]

why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The passive object needs to be set to *Shape > Mesh*, otherwise it will work as a closed object:

[image]

[image]